# Trigger a python program on opening a file

Tags: python, file

I want to create a standalone python 3.4 program that runs whenever a user double-clicks/opens a file (say an MS Word file).

I am working on Windows 7

Is such an arrangement possible?

Comment: Why not just change the file association to call a python program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could go about this is to create a python application (with something like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)), and at the end of your application, you would use something like [pywin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to launch your windows application.

After creating your exe, you would set it as your default application for opening the files you want it to "trigger" on.